# How to ignore query constraints when the parameter is empty or null in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Elastic Noob here, I have the following query for the elastic search index. in which I try to filter the records based on the title of the product record.

```
"query" => [
    "bool" => [
        "should" => [
            [
                "nested" => [
                    "path"  => "name",
                    "query" => [
                        "multi_match" => [
                            "query"  => (string) $query, // here the $query can be empty string
                            "fields" => ['name.en', 'name.ar'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now the parameter `$query` (please see the commented section in the sample code) can be an empty string. In that case, now I am getting zero results, Obviously because I don't have any records with an empty title.

**What I would like to get**

is to essentially ignore the query since the parameter is empty and to get a default result set back.

I have more queries like category, tags, reviews etc... so even when the name/title query is empty, I should be able to filter based on the other queries. But now if the `name` part is empty I am getting an empty result set.

Please post a comment if more info is needed

Elasticsearch 7

Comment: how about simply using `if/else` logic in PHP?

Comment: I could, but I was looking for more of an elastic search solution.

Comment: The query DSL is not an imperative language, but an declarative one, so there's no way of specifying any control flow.

Comment: Hmm.. so in that sense, there is no way to say that, if nothing matches fallback to `match_all` ?

Comment: Using `if/else` logic in PHP :-)

Comment: Can you show us the mapping for that index?

I think you're looking for a filtered bool query.
You could have a should with a `mininum_should_match` of 1, and the first should is a match for the exact term, while the second query could be a [missing query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-missing-query.html)

Answer (score 1):

In a `match` or `multi_match` query an empty string will be ingored if one uses `zero_terms_query` option, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "",
            "zero_terms_query": "all",
            "fields": ["name.en", "name.ar"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or `match` version:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "",
              "zero_terms_query": "all"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

See [zero terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-zero)